# Is there a difference between tinting K100 black and using a lower K value?

Tags: color, print-production

I just finished laying out a book that’s to be printed as 1+1. For table headers and a few other things, I used a light grey.

Now, for some reason (not sure why), I just realised I’ve defined all these greys as CMYK 0/0/0/100 tinted down to 15% or 7% or whatever the needed lightness was, rather than just defining them as CMYK 0/0/0/15 (or whatever) to begin with, which is what I’d usually do.

But then I wondered – is there actually any difference in this case? It’s a monochrome black, so presumably the tint and the lower K value (side question: what do you call a non-tint-based lightening like that?) will end up giving the same result. Or will it?

Is there, in the case of single-channel colours, any actual difference between tinting a 100% colour and defining a colour as less than 100% in that channel? If output format makes a difference, please assume offset printing, but I’d be interested to know if there’s ever any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, there is no difference between using a tint swatch and manually defining a swatch with lower values.

Even using opacity to lighten the color should yield the same result *if* the background is white.

You can easily check this by opening the *Separations Preview* panel, setting *View* to *Separations* and mouse over swatches defined in the different ways.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. On screen, the opacity one only gives the same result with overprint preview/simulation on, but when printed it will of course be the same.

Comment: oh my god! This is epic! you know soooooooo much! I love this answer.

Comment: is this true for all ( illustrator, photoshop and InDesign) ?

Comment: and also for web and print?

Comment: @NeverLookBack, uhm ... yes; i would say that (you make me wonder if there *might* be some exception ). But only on white background as mentioned. And in RGB it's a bit reversed as the values are not set in % ink. So for example a 50% tint of RGB(0,0,0) becomes RGB(127,127,127).

Answer (score -5):

if you wanna have a rich black: Keep the k at 100% and give some value to the CMY.
for example: C:35 M:35 Y:35 K:100
that would prevent your black to come out dull!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.