# Create gray color while printing

Tags: color, print-production

To use the color gray in black and white offset printing, which is used both in the text as a headline and in the context of some other pages, which method is better?

1. Reduce tint of black color, for example 50% in the desired parts?
2. Or should I make a copy of the black color and in the settings, set the black percentage to 50 with tint=100 percent?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  A tint of black is a percentage of black. They are the same thing. Sure some software may differentiate the two, but in offset lithography, they will give exactly the same result - i.e. a 50% halftone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between tinting K100 black and using a lower K value?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/138793/is-there-a-difference-between-tinting-k100-black-and-using-a-lower-k-value)

Comment: Yes, to make gray.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but one thing about option 2 that may make sense to do (regardless of setting via tint or percentage) is that setting specific swatches allows you to alter the swatch later and have the entire document (and any styles) reflect the change. Compare to having to hunt down each instance where a tint was applied individually.

Comment: What about this?
 to get the output for offset printing, what settings should be applied in the color putout menu? Part of the pages are two-tone and part black and white? All images are monotone. the monotone images for:two-color pages and black and white, is correct?
Does not have two black palettes cause problems when printing? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

> Reduce tint of black color, for example 50% in the desired parts?

This equates to a 50% screen for black on press.

> Or should I make a copy of the black color and in the settings, set the black percentage to 50 with tint=100 percent?

This equates to a 50% screen for black on press.

There is **no difference**.

If the desire is to *remove* any screens, then you *must* use a spot color to represent the 50% black. There's *no method* of altering a K value to less than 100% *anywhere* and still achieve a solid ink.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a swatch defining the K color to 50%.

In reality, I do not quite understand your second option. And this ignorance on my part is the fundament for my answer. You need to be perfectly clear on what the file is declaring.

If your file is indicating 100% Ink but somewhere else you are declaring that you need this value to be modified, is a potential problem.

Yes, you could use a spot ink, a middle gray for example, but that would be an additional ink. That is one way to interpret your instructions.

Comment: Means black copy is: c=0, m=0, y=0, black=50. Tint=100. Yes?